# Why isn't Hades forever?

Tags: biblical-basis, place-of-the-dead

As I understand it, Hades is one way of talking about the state before hell and heaven proper, one which is temporary and does not exist for saints. This is pretty basic, but I never studied theology at all.

Does the Bible say why this state is temporary?

Comment: It is temporary because both the heavens and the earth are to be altered. 'I shake not the earth only but the heavens also' Hebrews 12:26. Then all shall be changed, all of the dead shall be raised and a permanent, eternal state shall be ushered in. These things are plainly declared throughout the bible. You are correct : it is basic, but it is there to be read.

Comment: yeah I guess heaven needs to be populated by someone @NigelJ thanks

Comment: I'm not sure which Christians believe in a place like this subsequent to the Resurrection. This sounds like what I'd heard described as "The Bosom of Abraham"  (i.e. the place (or state, which is probably more theologically correct) that the O.T. Saints souls abided in prior to Jesus' descent into the dead).  Modern Protestant theology only acknowledges Heaven and Hell (while some universalists only acknowledge Heaven). You might be confusing this with the Catholic/Orthodox doctrine around Purgatory (which is a one-way street to Heaven).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We are different to many other sites, and this link explains why.  When you have a moment, please take our Tour to understand what we look for in researched questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour